# Change the gateway in a docker network

Tags: docker, subnet, gateway

I'm trying to create multiple dockers (from the same image) and put them in a subnet where I can work with them as if they were many machines.

```
version: "3"

services:
    machine001:
        container_name: "machine001"
        build: .
        image: "test-machine"
        ports:
            - "1337"
            - "22"
        networks:
            net:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.1.1

    machine002:
        container_name: "machine002"
        build: .
        image: "test-machine"
        ports:
            - "1337"
            - "22"
        networks:
            net:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.1.2

networks:
   net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24
```

When composing, however, I get an error for the first machine and I get an error that says `Address already in use` (the second one works just fine), so by browsing a little I thought that maybe the address `172.20.1.1` is reserved for the gateway and I tried changhing it, following [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656918/5839055)

```
services:
    # same as before...

networks:
   net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - driver: default
                  subnet: 172.20.1.0/24
                  gateway: 172.20.1.254
```

However, compose doesn't like that and it says

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   networks.net.ipam.config value Additional properties are not allowed ('gateway', 'driver' were unexpected)

What is the right way to change the gateway for the subnet? Would that make available the address `172.20.1.1`?

Answer (score 0):

In mi personal case, gateway no works in docker compose version 3, I had to return to version 2, after that all fine, I used docker network inspect network_name and I see now that has gateway that I defined.

**All this working in docker-compose**